# Re-using nested SQL statements within parent statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL code;

```
SELECT  a.*, b.maxDate as last_payment_date, c.package as payment_for_package, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM uploads WHERE user = a.id) AS upload_count
                FROM users a 
                    INNER JOIN payments c
                        ON a.id = c.user_id
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT user_id, MAX(date) maxDate, period
                        FROM payments
                        GROUP BY user_id
                    ) b ON c.user_id = b.user_id AND
                            c.date = b.maxDate

                WHERE a.package = 1
                AND b.maxDate < $twomonths
                AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM uploads WHERE user = a.id) > 10
                AND b.period = 1
                ORDER BY b.maxDate ASC
                LIMIT 50
```

As you can see I use the nested statement `(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM uploads WHERE user = a.id)` twice and I was wondering if there is a way to re-use this statement for improved performance? I've tried using the alias `upload_count` but you can't use alias' in `WHERE` clauses. Appreciate the help

Comment: Maybe you should backup and ask how to write a good query to get the data out (post the schema and some same data).  It's hard to believe that this query is the best that can be done, regardless of whether you can reuse parts of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join to the subquery and correlate the results:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.maxDate as last_payment_date,
    c.package as payment_for_package,
    upload_counts.upload_count

FROM users a 

INNER JOIN payments c
    ON a.id = c.user_id

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(date) maxDate, period
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY user_id
) b ON c.user_id = b.user_id AND
       c.date = b.maxDate

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user, COUNT(id) AS upload_count
    FROM uploads
    GROUP BY user
) upload_counts ON upload_counts.user = a.id

WHERE a.package = 1
AND b.maxDate < $twomonths
AND upload_counts.upload_count > 10
AND b.period = 1

ORDER BY b.maxDate ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: No problem.  Note that the speed increase was unlikely because the subquery was being executed twice in the original query, but because it was being executed twice *per result row*.  This version executes a query exactly once for the `uploads` table, over the entire query.